# Where should I save application data?

Tags: c#

I have tried many ways of getting a directory where I can save an application's .exe that needs to stay there, but every single directory I try says access denied.

What path should I be writing to for this? surely there has to be a path where Admin Permission isn't right? I am sure I have seen this be done before..

What have I tried?
This

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

This

```
Path.GetTempPath()
```

And this

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

Can anyone help here? here is my full code, maybe it has something to do with downloading?

```
string downloadUrl = "http://example.com/example.txt";
string savePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "/Fox/example.txt";

if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
}

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, savePath);
    Process.Start(savePath);
}
```

Usually getting an exception along these lines

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at App.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App\App\Program.cs:line 26

Inner Exception 1:
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\User\App\example.txt' is denied.
```

Line of exception:

```
client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, savePath);
```

Comment: If you're trying to easily download and execute an arbitrary executable file, you are no different than malware. The proper way to install executables in windows is an .msi file.

Comment: Who said anything about malware? This is also a personal project so it's nothing to do with malware's.

Comment: And if you're downloading an update to your app you should download it to users temp directory

Comment: @Dawid I did as you would know if you read my code. It's access denied.

Comment: The access is denied because what you are doing is exactly what malware typically does, and the OS is trying to keep your computer safe.

Comment: So I guess what I am asking is, how do I get around that? Install to the downloads location then copy it over to the temp directory?

Comment: The safe way to run new executables is to create an .msi package and install it. The easy way to run code from the Internet is to use javascript.

Comment: This isn't what I am asking, what I am asking is what directory gives access directly from downloading? surely some must..

Comment: Run your application as administrator. And be prepared to format your hard drive when you actively try to avoid your OS' security measures.

Comment: That isn't my question now is it? stay on topic please. What directory is accessible in my current situation?

Comment: One question: on what OS are you testing this app cause this code https://pastebin.com/UT9aVSmB works without any error. File is opened in notepad (as it's TXT file but I've tried with EXE and it worked too)

Comment: Hello, I tried this on Windows 10 in debug mode on VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `savePath` first to represent a directory...

```
if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
}
```

...and then to represent a file...

```
client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, savePath);
```

Attempting to download a file to `%UserProfile%\Fox\example.txt` will fail with the exception you specified when `example.txt` already exists as a directory.  The following snippet demonstrates that the problem you're having is not unique to file downloads:

```
// Build a path to a file/directory with a random name in the user's temp directory
// Does not guarantee that path does not already exist, but assume it doesn't
string path = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName()
);
// Create a directory at that path
DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

// Create a file at the same path
// Throws UnauthorizedAccessException with message "Access to the path '...' is denied."
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
{
}
```

Consider changing your code to the following to avoid this issue:

```
string downloadUrl = "http://example.com/example.txt";
string saveDirectoryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "/Fox";
string saveFilePath = saveDirectoryPath + "/example.txt";

if (!Directory.Exists(saveDirectoryPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDirectoryPath);
}

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, saveFilePath);
    Process.Start(saveFilePath);
}
```

Just a note, I'd recommend using [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of `string` concatenation when building paths:

```
string saveDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Fox");
string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectoryPath, "example.txt");
```

It's cross-platform and handles all the necessary logic for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a manifest file to your project to require administrator privileges for your executable might be a way of solving this issue.